# Code Igniter Models & libraries

Tags: codeigniter

in CI i created a model called "User" which has a method called "entries" and another one called "books"

I would like to pass a $user_id parameter to the model so it creates an instance of the class in my controller.

the way I currently call the model in the controller is :

```
$data1 = $this->user->entries($user_id);
$data2 = $this->user->books($user_id);
```

I would like to pass that user_id parameter directly to the constructor so that i dont have to use the $user_id parameter each time

perhaps something like this ( i know the syntax is wrong in this case):

```
$this->load->model('user',$user_id);
$data['row1'] = $this->user->entries();
$data['row2'] = $this->user->books();
```

Please forgive my lack of understand of OOP ..i just made the switch.
thanks for your help

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass variables to the constructor, but you could make a method to set the userID, and then use it.

Example:

```
class user extends CI_Model{

  var $user_id;

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function set_user_id($user_id){
    $this->$user_id = $user_id;
  }
}
```

And then inside your `entries` and `books` books method, you can use `$this->$user_id`, without needing to pass it again.

Like so:

```
  function entries(){
    $user_id = $this->user_id;
  }
```

Comment: it crossed my mind, but then I thought that perhaps there is a better reason why i should not do it since this is not as "simple" as everything else in CI. Basically I am trying to understand if my logic is wrong and if should avoid passing variable to models all together and use this class as a library instead of model...just some thoughts

Comment: @salmane: Models are used to interact with the database.  They can contain methods to get and set data in the database.  I suggest sending parameters to each function, so they can act independently from each other.

Comment: @Rocket thank you. just so i better understand it in CI the model does not create an instance of an object unlike a php class?

Comment: @salmane: When a CI model is loaded it's created and then added to the `$this` object, so you can do `$this->Model_name`.